# Accessing elements from an array in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays

I am trying to access individual elements of my array. This is an example of the contents of the array i am trying to access.

```
<City: 0x4b77fd0> (entity: Spot; id: 0x4b7e580 <x-coredata://D902D50B-C945-42E2-8F71-EDB62222C0A7/Spot/p5> ; data: {
    CityToProvince = 0x4b7dbd0 <x-coredata://D902D50B-C945-42E2-8F71-EDB62222C0A7/County/p15>;
    Description = "Friend";
    Email = "bla@bla.com";
    Age = 21;
    Name = "Adam";
    Phone = "+44175240";
}),
```

The elements i am trying to access are Name, Phone, etc ...

How would i go about doing this?

**UPDATE:**
OK, understanding that I am looking at core data now, how would I go about removing an object from being displayed in my table view?

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSManagedObject *object = (NSManagedObject *)[entityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }



    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't look like an array.  That looks like a Core Data entity.  You may have an array *of* them, but it appears as though you're trying to access the members of the entity itself.  To do so, you can use the NSManagedObject method [`-(id) valueForKey:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/valueForKey:).

```
NSManagedObject *entity = /* ... retrieve entity from Core Data ... */;
NSString *name = [entity valueForKey:@"Name"];
```